# How to save something to the desktop without hard-coding the directory?

Tags: java, user-interface, text

I was wondering how to get java to save a text file named `hello.txt` to the desktop without writing

```
"C:\\Users\\Austin\\Desktop"
```

Any help would be great. so like:

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName.getText(), true);
```

..and the `fileName.getText()` is just going to be the 'hello'.

UPDATE:
i think that i would be able to use the jfilechooser, so would this work?

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setVisible(true);
```

would that work? and if so, how would i get it to save the file using the selection in there?
im a noob.... :(

Comment: If you know the operating system, then you may use User Home folder shortcut name for creating a full Desktop directory relative to user home.

Comment: `C:\\Users\\NoAustin\\Desktop`.... can you be a more specific in stating what you want? Do you just want to get the home directory from environment or is it something else?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java

Comment: well, im thinking for mac and windows, and so what is the user home folder shortcut for windows 7>

Comment: I don't know of any simple OS-agnostic solution to this. You will likely have to create a solution for each platform.

Comment: ok, but what is the user home folder shortcut for windows 7?

Comment: I recommend you read the desktop file path from a configuration file.  Then it isn't hardcoded in your program.

Comment: i dont know what that means...

Comment: *"would that work?"*  I figure you could have tried that in the time I waited to reply.  What happened when you did (try it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;

class FindDesktopOnWindows {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win")<0) {
            System.err.println("Sorry, Windows only!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        File desktopDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        System.out.println(desktopDir.getPath() + " " + desktopDir.exists());

        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(desktopDir);
    }
}
```

I forgot different Locales. **Very fragile code** (even for code that starts out OS specific). See my comment below re. OS X/`JFileChooser`.

> ..how the `(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop")` works..

Oracle helpfully provides docs for this kind of thing.

See [`System.getProperty(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) & 
[`new File(String,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

---

I'll cede to an expert (or a user) on this, but I don't think OS X supports any application icons or document icons directly on the ..start screen, default look, whatever.. Probably better to offer the end user a `JFileChooser` pointing to `user.home` and ask them to save the document to the desktop (or wherever they feel like).

Comment: alright, explain how the `(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop")` works please?

Comment: alright. so i cant find how to make the jfilechooser... and so could u  give an example on just the basics? like just creating a jframe, but make this pop up, and make it be able to save?

Comment: well, im trying to do this for free. its for a school project

Comment: +1 for `suggesting JFileChooser`. On Mac OS X, the `user.home` property yields the correct path. "Desktop" is a valid directory name, even if it's been [localized](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37237/20589).

Answer (score 3):

This points you on desktop dir:

```
javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory()
```

Comment: On windows it does, not Linux though :(.

Comment: try: File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");

Answer (score 0):

User.home works, but just hardcoding the directory should be just fine.