# How does Java resolve a relative path in new File()?

Tags: java, file, relative-path

I am trying to understand the way Java resolves relative path in while creating a `File` object.

OS used: Windows

For the below snippet, I am getting an `IOException` as it cannot find the path:

```
@Test
public void testPathConversion() {
        File f = new File("test/test.txt");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(f.getPath());
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());    
            System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

My understanding here is, Java treats the path provided as absolute and returns an error when the path does not exist. So it makes sense.

When I update the above code to use relative path:

```
@Test
    public void testPathConversion() {
        File f = new File("test/../test.txt");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(f.getPath());
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());    
            System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
```

It creates a new file and provides the below output:

```
test\..\test.txt
C:\JavaForTesters\test\..\test.txt
C:\JavaForTesters\test.txt
```

In this case, my assumption is, even though the path provided doesn't exist, because the path contains "/../", java treats this as a relative path and creates the file in the `user.dir`.  So this also makes sense.

But if I update the relative path as below:

```
   @Test
    public void testPathConversion() {
        File f = new File("test/../../test.txt");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            System.out.println(f.getPath());
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Then I get IOException: Access is denied.

My questions are:

1. why `"test/../test.txt"` is treated as a relative path and creates the file in `"user.dir"` but`"test/../../test.txt"` returns an error? Where does it attempt to create the file for the path `"test/../../test.txt"`?
2. When the specified relative path is not found, the file seems to be created in the `user.dir`. So, it appears to me that the below two scenarios does the same thing:

   ```
   //scenario 1
   File f = new File("test/../test.txt");
   f.createNewFile();

   //scenario 2
   File f = new File("test.txt");
   f.createNewFile();
   ```

So is there a real world case where one would use scenario 1 instead of scenario 2?

I suppose I am missing something obvious here or have fundamentally misunderstood relative paths. I went through the Java docs for File and I am not able to find an explanation for this. There are quite a few questions posted in Stack Overflow regarding relative paths, but the ones I looked up were for specific scenarios and not exactly about how relative paths are resolved.

It will be great if someone could please explain me how this works or point to some related links?

Comment: Note that `user.dir` is a quite variable place that it would be fragile for an application to rely on.  Another factor to consider is that the app. might not be installed in a place where it *has write permissions.**  It would be more optimal & robust to make the file in (a sub-directory of) `user.home`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10166623/418556) for a short example.

Comment: Note: `test/test.txt` and `test/../test.txt` are both relative paths. Relative in this meaning has nothing to do with the presence of embedded `..` components.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a concept of a `working directory`.
This directory is represented by a `.` (dot).
In relative paths, everything else is relative to it.

Simply put the `.` (the working directory) is where you run your program. 
In some cases the working directory can be changed but in general this is 
 
what the dot represents. I think this is `C:\JavaForTesters\` in your case.

So `test\..\test.txt` means: the sub-directory `test` 
in my working directory, then one level up, then the 
file `test.txt`. This is basically the same as just `test.txt`.

For more details check here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Answer (score 15):

When your path starts with a root dir i.e. `C:\` in windows or `/` in Unix or in java resources path, it is considered to be an absolute path. Everything else is relative, so

```
new File("test.txt") is the same as new File("./test.txt")

new File("test/../test.txt") is the same as new File("./test/../test.txt")
```

The major difference between `getAbsolutePath` and `getCanonicalPath` is that the first one concatenates a parent and a child path, so it may contain dots: `..` or `.`. `getCanonicalPath` will always return the same path for a particular file.

Note: `File.equals` uses an abstract form of a path (`getAbsolutePath`) to compare files, so this means that two `File` objects for the same might not be equal and `File`s are unsafe to use in collections like `Map` or `Set`.

Answer (score 6):

The working directory is a common concept across virtually all operating systems and program languages etc. It's the directory in which your program is running. This is usually (but not always, there are ways to change it) the directory the application is in.

Relative paths are ones that start without a drive specifier. So in linux they don't start with a `/`, in windows they don't start with a `C:\`, etc. These always start from your working directory.

Absolute paths are the ones that start with a drive (or machine for network paths) specifier. They always go from the start of that drive.

Answer (score 5):

Relative paths can be best understood if you know how Java runs the program.

There is a concept of working directory when running programs in Java. Assuming you have a class, say, `FileHelper` that does the IO under 
`/User/home/Desktop/projectRoot/src/topLevelPackage/`.

Depending on the case where you invoke `java` to run the program, you will have different working directory. If you run your program from within and IDE, it will most probably be `projectRoot`.

- In this case `$ projectRoot/src : java topLevelPackage.FileHelper` it will be `src`.
- In this case `$ projectRoot : java -cp src topLevelPackage.FileHelper` it will be `projectRoot`.
- In this case `$ /User/home/Desktop : java -cp ./projectRoot/src topLevelPackage.FileHelper` it will be `Desktop`.

`(Assuming $ is your command prompt with standard Unix-like FileSystem. Similar correspondence/parallels with Windows system)`

So, your relative path root `(.)` resolves to your working directory. Thus to be better sure of where to write files, it's said to consider below approach.

```
package topLevelPackage

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileHelper {

    // Not full implementation, just barebone stub for path
    public void createLocalFile() {

        // Explicitly get hold of working directory
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        Path filePath = Paths.get(workingDir+File.separator+"sampleFile.txt");

        // In case we need specific path, traverse that path, rather using . or .. 
        Path pathToProjectRoot = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop", "projectRoot");

        System.out.println(filePath);
        System.out.println(pathToProjectRoot);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

On windows and Netbeans you can set the relative path as:

```
    new FileReader("src\\PACKAGE_NAME\\FILENAME");
```

On Linux and Netbeans you can set the relative path as:

```
    new FileReader("src/PACKAGE_NAME/FILENAME");
```

If you have your code inside `Source Packages`
I do not know if it is the same for eclipse or other IDE

Answer (score 2):

Only slightly related to the question, but try to wrap your head around this one.  So un-intuitive:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path p1 = Paths.get("/personal/./photos/./readme.txt");
    Path p2 = Paths.get("/personal/index.html");
    Path p3 = p1.relativize(p2);
    System.out.println(p3); //prints  ../../../../index.html  !!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I went off of peter.petrov's answer but let me explain where you make the file edits to change it to a relative path.

Simply edit "AXLAPIService.java" and change

`url = new URL("file:C:users..../schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl");`

to

`url = new URL("file:./schema/current/AXLAPI.wsdl");`

or where ever you want to store it.

You can still work on packaging the wsdl file into the meta-inf folder in the jar but this was the simplest way to get it working for me.