# Using Scanner to read text file and print using List

Tags: java, java-io

This is for a homework assignment, for a game of Hangman. Now, I got the whole game working except for this part. Reading the dictionary list that the teacher provided.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(words.txt));

    List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {

        dictionary.add(fileScan.nextLine().toLowerCase());
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < dictionary.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(dictionary.get(i));
    }
}
```

I separated this part from the code to be able to test it. I also made the dictionary file into just 5 words. When I hit run, it doesn't print out anything. Just a blank space.

Comment: have you tried to print it `fileScan.nextLine().toLowerCase()` to check if it has a value?

Comment: don't forget to close your resource; add a fileScan.close(); after your while loop is through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`words.txt` must be `quoted` 'coz it's a string.

like this

```
 Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
```

also make sure that the file path of your txtfile is correct. you can use either [**ABSOLUTE PATH**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/) OR [**RELATIVE PATH**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060992/how-does-java-resolve-a-relative-path-in-new-file)

when printing all the data, you can also simply do it like this using `foreach`

```
for(String item:dictionary){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Comment: So, I tried this and when I run in command prompt, this appears: 
"ÿ?i

 a

 a d". I just don't get why those 2 symbols appear in front of the first one.

Comment: what do you mean by this `"ÿ?i a a d"` ?  is there an error?

Comment: I am so sorry. I should have said more. It is outputting correctly except for the ""ÿ?". Those two symbols are nowhere in the dictionary file. "i a ad" should be the only output.

Comment: did you use foreach for print it or you use for loop?

Comment: I used the one you gave me, the foreach

Comment: what is your encoding type of your textfile?

Comment: i get it now, the problem because your output console is not supporting the UTF-8 data

Comment: read this to understand more, http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-data-from-a-file-java/

Comment: if you print it on your IDE like netbeans or eclipse etc., maybe that symbol won't appear

Comment: Unicode. I am slowly adding words and those two symbols seem to only appear on the first term. Which should be fine for my game since a random word is going to be selected from a huge list. But it would be nice to fix this problem now.