# Where to store a text file when importing data?

Tags: java, resources

I have created a JDBC in Netbeans which loads data into the tables from a text file. When I run the program on a different computer, the file path (I think thats what it is called) will be different.

The text file is on my desktop. This means if I have to run the program from a different computer I would get an error because the file was obviously not found in the same place as on the original computer.

I created a string to load the data into the database, shown below:

```
String loadData = "load data local infile '/Users/Ricky/Desktop/table_data.txt'" +
                      "into table T1;";
```

Could I create a folder in the netbeans project to store the text file? So it could be accessed from any computer with the same path?

Comment: A possible solution is to use [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) (`user.home` for example) or a custom property

Comment: Where do you run your program?  On your desktop?  Or is this a web app or something like that?  Edit: also, is it always the same text file, or can the text file be different?

Comment: Take the location instead as a commandline parameter or other such mechanism. There's no sense in hardcoding the location.

Comment: NETNEANS (also known as NetBeans) can create many kinds of apps, including both desktop and web apps.  Please answer the question explicitly.

Comment: There are several ways to solve this. Which solution to choose is up to you. Some of them: 1) if the file won't change and it depends merely on the project, then locate the file as a resource and let it be packaged as part of your jar 2) if the file can/should/must be changed by final users, then let it outside of the jar and let the client set a variable to locate the file 3) if the file can/should change its content, place it in a default place relative to the location of the jar as default, and provide to the clients the ability to set a new file and the path where this file can be consumed

Comment: As Luiggi's long comment implies, there are *many* possible solutions here, and they all depend on your intended usage.  There is no single "best" answer.  Please give us more details.  I like the command line parameter suggestion, but a simple GUI interface might also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use relative paths, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21061094/3794552)

What you have to do is instead of using an **absolute location** (i.e. 'C:\FolderName\filename.txt'), use a **relative location** (i.e. 'table_data.txt') instead.

In your case, this translates to using

```
String loadData = "load data local infile 'table_data.txt'" +
                      "into table T1;";
```

What this does is load the file from the **same folder as where you ran your application from**.

---

Another solution is to use a [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), which allows the user to find the file from whatever directory it's saved on.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program from the same directory as the data file, then you could use:

```
String loadData = "load data local infile 'table_data.txt'" +
                  "into table T1;";
```

By specifying no path, the program will look in the current working directory (the directory you started the program from).

Answer (score 0):

You can have an optional command line argument:

```
public class Main {

    private static final String LOAD_COMMAND = "load data local infile '%s' into table T1;";
    private static final String DEFAULT_FILE = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/table_data.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_FILE;
        String command = String.format(LOAD_COMMAND, file);
        System.out.println(command);
    }
}
```

If you saved the above in `Main.java`, you could easily test it.

```
javac Main.java && java -cp . Main
```

would print:

```
load data local infile '/Users/<your-username>/table_data.txt' into table T1;
```

And

```
javac Main.java && java -cp . Main /my/file
```

would print:

```
# load data local infile '/my/file' into table T1;
```