# How to create path in java

Tags: java

how to create a path in java without define the folder location?
for example:

```
String directory = "/works/abc/"
File fileDirectory = new File(directory );
```

This directory may be can save at local c, or may be can save at local D. When user change location disk, so that java can auto find that folder.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a [relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060992/how-does-java-resolve-a-relative-path-in-new-file)?

Answer (score 2):

Using the nio api:

```
Path directory = Paths.get("/works/abc/");
Path drive = Paths.get("C:/"); // e.g.
Path result = drive.resolve(directory); // result: C:\works\abc
```

If you really need a file, you can use `result.toFile()`