# How to find the path of a file local eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a .txt file in my Eclipse Java project, and I want to find out the path to it so I can use it for a Scanner. I ***do not*** want to find out the path on my local drive, as I will be planning to share the program to someone else, and they will have a different folder structure, rather a path that can be used on anybodies machine.

Here is the code:

```
this.file = new File("<insert path here>");
```

Comment: I think this question can help you:<br>
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/21060992/7405620](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21060992/7405620)

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Do you want to get the path programmatically?

Comment: @user12346352 I'm trying to find a good way of explaining it... is there a way to get a path that can be used no matter who has the source code (So not starting from my C: drive ) ?

Comment: Have you considered using the `args` parameter of your main method so you can simply be given the absolute path from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

= new File("Build Path"); (your .java file exist in your build path)

The **build** path is used for building your application. It contains all of your source files and all Java libraries that are required to compile the application.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, the default behavior is for the Java system property `user.dir` to be set to the project directory. This is what dictates where the "root" of File operations is. So if you created a file `test.txt` in the root project directory, you should be able to access it with `new File("test.txt")`.

However, as [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) mentioned in his comment, the more correct method would be using [embedded resources](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 0):

Try one of These:

1.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

2.

```
File currentDirFile = new File(".");
String helper = currentDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
String currentDir = helper.substring(0, helper.length() - currentDirFile.getCanonicalPath().length());//this line may need a try-catch
```

I have not tested it just found while googling