# Why do I get an error saying that the program can't find my text file

Tags: java

I am simply trying to make a very basic java program to read a file. However I get the error that it can't find my file:
`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: read.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`
I checked and I have not misspelled my file name, and the file is already in the same file directory as the program.
Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class save_files {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("read.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

    }
}
```

Comment: Put the file at project root folder to make this work.

Comment: Try putting the full path of the text file in there and see if your code works. :)

Comment: @SureshAtta What do you mean by root folder?

Comment: @arcanium0611 Yes, thank you that worked, however is there an easier way to do it as I also code in python and know that if its in the same file directory you only have to put the file

Comment: If you're working in eclipse or intelliJ, try adding the file to your project through the IDE. That usually works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"read.txt" is a relative file path, relative to the 'working dir'. Be sure to specify the path relative to the working dir.

See this answer:
[How does Java resolve a relative path in new File()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060992/how-does-java-resolve-a-relative-path-in-new-file)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try the absolute path to the file first. If your code works (which it should), then your problem is the relative path, which also depends on how you're running your code.

If you're using something like NetBeans or Eclipse, your code will work if your file is in the root directory for the project. If your project was named `Foo`, your directory could look something like this:

```
Foo
|- build
|- nbproject
|- src
|- test
|- build.xml
|- manifest.mf
|- read.txt
```

Otherwise, if you're doing something like running a `.jar` from the command line, the context of "where to find read.txt" will depend on your working directory. If the path is a literal (your case) it will look on the working directory.