# Why am I getting file doesn't exist?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, hsqldb, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to run an app with acquiadevdesktop with this code:

```
 Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevDesktop\\AcquiaDevDesktop\\AcquiaDevDesktop2.exe");
        pb.start();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("AcquiaDevDesktop2"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HConnexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Yet I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: AcquiaDevDesktop2 doesn't exist.
at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.checkFileValidation(Desktop.java:367)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:427)
at DataBase.HConnexion.run_wamp(HConnexion.java:88)
at DataBase.HConnexion.connectDb(HConnexion.java:35)
at DataBase.DBcontrol.creer_piece(DBcontrol.java:105)
at pdr.FrontController.initialize(FrontController.java:160)
....
```

What can I try to fix it?

Comment: What kind of object is `pb`? You must specify the path. This can be [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060992/how-does-java-resolve-a-relative-path-in-new-file) or absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the filetype, because `new File()` can't assume what type it is.

For example, if it's a text file, it should be: `new File("AcquiaDevDesktop2.txt"));`

Comment: Try specifying the direct path then. You can see the direct math by Right Clicking and then selecting Properties.

Comment: so i did that, now i don't know if it worked or not but i'm getting a new error now :java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.cnn" is null
 at DataBase.DBcontrol.creer_piece(DBcontrol.java:122)
 at pdr.FrontController.initialize(FrontController.java:160)

Comment: @zeeilyas that has nothing to do with the code in your question (not in any obvious way, at least). Try to debug that problem by yourself and, in case, create a new question.