# Where could I save a log file in a server using web wervice JAVA (.war)?

Tags: java, file, web-services, server, save

I create a web service using JAVA. I want to create a log file in the server to recover it later but my problem is that I cannot save the file due to client rights.
In my local server, I can save it in the root path, but in the Devian server where I will use it, this is not possible.
I try to change the path, but the problem remains because my local paths are different than other server.
This is my code:

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
            FileWriter fw = null;
            try {           
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"zlm_"+thoy+".txt");
                // Si el archivo no existe, se crea!
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                // flag true, indica adjuntar información al archivo.
                fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(entrada+";"+porcentaje+";");               
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                                //Cierra instancias de FileWriter y BufferedWriter
                    if (bw != null)
                        bw.close();
                    if (fw != null)
                        fw.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) 
{
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend putting it in /var/log or in the /tmp directory. If you still don't have permissions to those directories, you can always put it in the relative/working directory of the war file.

More on how to create files in the working directory in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060992/how-does-java-resolve-a-relative-path-in-new-file).

Answer (score 1):

Make the path to the log file configurable so the server admin can set it. Ask the admin for a path to test it on.