# How to change JFileChooser start directory to desktop?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change `JFileChooser` start directory to desktop. So, in my computer I wrote:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("C:\\Users\\LNK\\Desktop");
```

The problem is, when I compile my code and run program in another computer it doesn't work because there are no `C:\\Users\\LNK\\Desktop` path. So, is there some kind of "apsolute" path of desktop?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java ?

Answer (score 13):

**You can use a `user.home` system property to get user directory**.
So your code would look like

```
String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(userDir +"/Desktop");
```

Comment: I think you mean `System.getProperty("user.home")`.  Concatenating "/Desktop" will work on Windows, Mac OS X, and even Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option for getting to the Windows desktop:

```
fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\"));
Action details = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("Go Up");
details.actionPerformed(null);
details.actionPerformed(null);
```

If you leave off the last line, you will get to "Computer"

Answer (score 0):

use this ,

```
String desktopPath = WindowsUtils.getCurrentUserDesktopPath();
```

Comment: What the heck is `WindowsUtils`?

Comment: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/os/WindowsUtils.html - apparently.