# creating folders for all users

Tags: java, path, directory

I am trying to create a folder by running java. As of now I have this and it works.

```
File f = new File ("/Users/myName/Desktop/nameOfDir");
f.mkdirs();
```

The question is what happens when I send this code to my friend? Would he have to change the code to the below for it to work?

```
File f = new File ("/Users/myFriendsName/Desktop/nameOfDir");
f.mkdirs();
```

how can I make the program find the correct path and create the folder where I want it (the desktop), regardless of who the user is?

Also, after creating the folder I will have to create a .txt in the folder. I can do this now, but same problem arise concerning different user names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the Desktop path in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java)

Comment: this is not a duplicate, (atleast not to the question linked), I dont ask how to create a folder, I ask how to get the path correct acording to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the following:

```
String userName = System.getProperty("user.name"); //platform independent 
File f = new File ("/Users/" + userName + "/Desktop/nameOfDir");
f.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Note that whilst the username is retrieved in a platform-independent way here, the path constructed for `f` will only work on certain platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to a user's home directory in a platform-independent way using:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

So:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop/nameOfDir");
f.mkdirs();
```