# How to get the Desktop path in Java 9 on Mac

Tags: java, macos, java-9

Java 9 prevents direct use of com.apple.eio.FileManager. Until now I've used this on Mac to get the location of the user's "Desktop" path, as follows

```
public static File getDesktopFolder() throws FileNotFoundException {
    final int desktopOSType = FileManager.OSTypeToInt("desk");
    final String desktopFolderName = FileManager.findFolder(desktopOSType);
    return new File(desktopFolderName);
}
```

Is there a replacement in Java 9 for using com.apple.eio.FileManager to find the Desktop? My temporary solution is to use the answer to [the similar Windows-oriented question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java):

```
public static File getDesktopFolder() {
    return new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
}
```

However this seems brittle and potentially buggy in certain locales or on certain strangely-configured systems.

Answer (score 3):

[Platform-Specific Desktop Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-97C1D0BB-D5D3-4CAD-B17D-03A87A0AAF3B) have been removed in JDK9.

> The APIs in the `com.apple.eawt` and `com.apple.eio` packages are
>   encapsulated, so you won’t be able to compile against them in JDK 9.
>   However, they remain accessible at runtime, so existing code that is
>   compiled to old versions continues to run.
>
> Eventually, libraries or applications that use the internal classes in the `apple`and `com.apple`
>   packages and their subpackages will need to migrate to the new API.

The new API to migrate the code instead as proposed in the *[JEP:272](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/272)* is **[`java.awt.Desktop`.](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)**
Though I can see `edit`, `open`, `browse` etc stubs within the same API, yet all of them need a legal specified path name and none of them creates one according to the docs.

Also, I am not very sure of why you would find the existing approach as brittle and buggy for the purpose of creating a file on a user's desktop.

```
return new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
```

---

An alternate way/temporary hack to make use of your existing code in Java 9, when you might end up getting an error similar  to

> ```
> Error:(3, 17) java: package com.apple.eio is not visible   (package
> com.apple.eio is declared in module java.desktop, which does not
> export it)
> ```

is to make use of [`--add-exports` as proposed in Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) during compilation

```
--add-exports java.desktop/com.apple.eio=ALL-UNNAMED
```