# How to save an xml file to local desktop in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have created an xml file and I want to save it to my desktop but I have no clue how to do that type of thing.

here is my code thus far:

```
// create xml
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory =
            DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document testDoc = builder.newDocument();

        Element bo = testDoc.createElement("bo");
        bo.setAttribute("type", "Employee");
        bo.setAttribute("id", emp.getId());
        testDoc.appendChild(bo);

        Element username = testDoc.createElement("username");
        username.setTextContent(emp.getUsername());
        bo.appendChild(username);

        Element passHash = testDoc.createElement("passwordHash");
        passHash.setTextContent(emp.getPasswordHash());
        bo.appendChild(passHash);

        Element passwordSalt = testDoc.createElement("passwordSalt");
        passwordSalt.setTextContent(emp.getPasswordSalt());
        bo.appendChild(passwordSalt);

        Element name = testDoc.createElement("name");
        name.setTextContent(emp.getName());
        bo.appendChild(name);

        Element lastLogin = testDoc.createElement("lastLogin");


        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("date = " + emp.getLastLogin());
        String date = df.format(emp.getLastLogin());
        lastLogin.setTextContent(date);
        bo.appendChild(lastLogin);

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(testDoc);

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(emp.getId() + ".xml");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ps);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
            .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you've figured out to build and write XML to a file, and are really asking how to create the file on the user's desktop.

If so, read the accepted answer to [In java under Windows, how do I find a redirected Desktop folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder)

Incidentally, the solution is not Windows specific.

Comment: I know it seems weird but I am sincerely fried and really outside my programming comfort zone. thanks!

Comment: +1, for interpreting the question (and giving a solution). All the XML code led me on a wild goose chase. I wonder why the answer hasn't been accepted yet?