# Write File to Desktop

Tags: java, file, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In java under Windows, how do I find a redirected Desktop folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder)
>   [How to get the Desktop path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java)

I want to write my results to the desktop of the user rather than to the same directory as file class that I am running.

I am using Mac OS.. How about in Window?1

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In java under Windows, how do I find a redirected Desktop folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder) or [How to get the Desktop path in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java)

Comment: Have you tried to write it to the desktop? Did you get any errors? We need more details really

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder/570536#570536

Comment: Related also to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java

Comment: @BaliC this is the point I do not know how to write to desktop assume I want to write this file

 bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFileStr));

Comment: @ThomasOwens neither of these provide an answer actually. FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory() _will not_ give you your Desktop path

Comment: @Oleg I never said either of those questions had the correct answer. However, they are asking the same thing. If an answer in either of those questions is incorrect, you should comment on it explaining why, downvote it, upvote a correct answer in the question, and/or provide a correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user's home directory is:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

In general +"/Desktop" would do, but is not portable.

```
String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
File textFile = new File(userHomeFolder, "mytext.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile));
try {
    ...
} finally {
   out.close();
}
```

This would write the file "mytext.txt" to the home directory.

Comment: thanks and how do I use it with 

bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Results"));

Comment: at least this is better than using `getHomeDirectory()`