# How can I make a BufferedWriter in java print to a file in the user's desktop?

Tags: java

I have a buffered writer, How can I make it put text file in the user's desktop, currently I have to specify a location and I cannot choose it to be the user's desktop location, doesn't matter who is logged in.

```
private static void writingFile() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writeArrayList = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter("D:\\text.txt"));
            for(GetArray s : arrayList){
                writeArrayList.write(s.toString() + "\r\n");
            }
            writeArrayList.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks.

---------------------Edited----------------------------Code improved-----------

```
try {
        File homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        File file = new File(homeDir, "Desktop");
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedWriter writeArrayList = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oStream));
            for(GetArray s : arrayList){
                writeArrayList.write(s.toString() + "\r\n");
            }
            writeArrayList.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be either a duplicate of or very similar to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *maybe?*

```
File homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
File file = new File(homeDir, "Desktop");
FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(oStream));
```

The Desktop is a an OS specific concept. So you have to know the address scheme of the OS. Like in OSX it's user.home/Desktop, Windows might be something like user.home/My Desktop, linux ... eh depends on if you have a X environment or not and if there is anything on top of that, like gnome, kde, etc.

Comment: Hi, is there a one line code for this, if not would it be possible if I give user the option to select a location instead of me entering it in the java program. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah you can specify the file to point to whereever you want, I just spelled it out for clarity. But you asked specifically for the desktop.

Comment: Well, that part of your code that has `new FileWriter()` you could adapt what I am doing here, or you could just remove that line entirely put my code in and rename the `BufferedWriter` to `writeArrayList`

Comment: Hi, it does not work, red messages appear in the console of eclipse.

Comment: Red messages you say? might need a new computer. ;) So That isn't helpful. Might be worthwhile to post your code or what you have done. I can only help so much. This task requires that you have basic java knowledge and filesystem knowledge

Comment: Hi, sorry for not posting the code here, I have editing my question, could you please check, again I am sorry completely forgot. thanks.

Comment: Again what is the problem?  Voting for close. This is getting sort of nuts. My only advise might be to check to see if the directory "Desktop" exists and/or create it. But basically you need to know the path of the "Desktop" for the User and Operating System scheme you are using.