# How do I transfer information from a folder to file?

Tags: java, file, output, directory

So I'm working on this progject that helps build a website for me and I'm looking to read from a folder (that has files) and write to an html document. I did a little research but I always end up having nothing printed or an error. Let me know if there is a way to do this? This is my project and I've changed the folder location and the output to .txt

```
public class Project {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

    Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Location")).forEach(filePath -> {
        if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {

            out.print(filePath);

            }    
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing to console as well? Does anything show up?

Comment: Yes when I print the the console everything shows up.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with File.isRegularFile(Path p). Are you looking for a file that is not a directory?

Comment: "output.txt" is probably being made at the root of your hard drive, at C:/, which you may not have write permission to.

Comment: You probably want to use `println` rather than `print`, and you need to close the writer (`out.close()`).

Comment: @ILikeTau, we can't assume he is at the root of his hd because he references "C:/Location" instead of just "Location".

Comment: @lacraig2 This part take some thumbnails that I have and starts to organize them. So it checks to see if it is a picture and it then is suppose to add the name of it to a file so I can then add more information to that file. So I can build part of a website without having to think about.

Comment: No, he can get it to output with println, so it's a file writing problem. I think the output.txt is being made somewhere he does not have write access.

Comment: @Andreas I just tried that and it still didn't work :/

Comment: @ILikeTau From what I understand that is my problem. Is there anyway to get around that?

Comment: Yes, your file isn't writing. Try using a path to your documents folder, somewhere you know you have write access.

Comment: @ILikeTau How would I do something like that?

Comment: @JoetheDailyProgrammer are all the photos in one folder or are their subdirectories?

Comment: @lacraig2 one folder

Comment: @JoetheDailyProgrammer, `System.getProperty("user.home")` points to homedir. Also PrintWriter tends to throw `FileNotFoundException` if it has no write access to provided file... Maybe, problem is with relative paths?

Comment: @ankhzet so I should replace that with the PrintWriter I have?

Comment: Yes, make it `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\output.txt");`

Comment: @JoetheDailyProgrammer do you need the file name e.g.) output.txt or the entire file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoetheDailyProgrammer, you probably writing in wrong file. Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File out = new File("output.txt");

    System.out.println(out.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Run it, and it will show absolute path to yours `"output.txt"`. If it points into different location, than you expected, then use absolute paths in yours app or use users homedir, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     File outFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/output.txt"); // file into users homedir

     System.out.println(outFile.getAbsolutePath()); // print it's location in console

     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile); // writer over that file

     Files.walk(Paths.get("C:/Location")).forEach(filePath -> {
         if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {

             out.print(filePath);

             }    
         }); 
     out.close();
    }
}
```

**Upd.**

If it's **really** yours intention to save file into desktop folder, then probably you should navigate it like in the following answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080900/2109067

https://stackoverflow.com/a/570536/2109067

So:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    File outFile = new File(fsv.getHomeDirectory() + "/output.txt"); // file into desktop dir

    System.out.println(outFile.getAbsolutePath()); // print it's location in console
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use PrintWriter("output.txt", true) to autoflush or flush it at the end of your program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
  File dir = new File("images");
  String[] list = dir.list();
  if (list != null) {
    for (String f : list) {
      String[] fileName = f.split("\\.");
      if (fileName.length > 1 && fileName[1].equals("png")) {
        // System.out.println(f);
        out.println(f);
      }

    }
  } else {
    System.out.println("list returned null because dir.canRead is " + dir.canRead());
  }
}
```

I rewrote a bit of it in the File class instead. Let me know if any of this needs changed. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting this problem right here                                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Project.main(Project.java:14)

Comment: Try running Files.canRead(Your file) to see if you can access it.

Comment: @JoetheDailyProgrammer try it now.

Comment: It says I can. Could it be something with Eclipse?

Comment: @JoetheDailyProgrammer Try creating a new folder in eclipse (Ctrl N -> select folder). Name it whatever you want. Then change "output.txt" to "whateveryounamedyourfolder/output.txt". Additionally, I would recommend you copy that file to your desktop, change the path, and try it there.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, one of the other members ending up getting a little closer to solving it with me; so I gave him the correct answer but I made sure to up-vote your response because it lead us to be closer. Thanks again for the help.