# Creating a file on User directory in Java

Tags: java

My code is posted below. Let's say my username is ThisPC, if I write like this: "C:\Users\ThisPC\Desktop\Lista Produse.txt" it is working as intended, saving my file on desktop, but when I try with %USERNAME% it is not working. (Keep in mind I'm using Java)  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
try{
File f=new File("C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop\\List.txt");
Formatter x;            
x=new Formatter("C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Desktop\\List.txt");            

while(enALL.hasMoreElements()){                
    x.format(""+enALL.nextElement());
    x.format("\r\n");
 }
        x.close(); 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Error.");
    }
```

Comment: I assume you're working Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that Java has no reason to parse the path that you supply, it is not a windows command shell.
To get the current username, try

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

and substitute it in.

However, this is still dangerous, as user directories on Windows can be located in different places, or without the full user name. 
see [In java under Windows, how do I find a redirected Desktop folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570401/in-java-under-windows-how-do-i-find-a-redirected-desktop-folder)

For  a more detailed option, that will be more reliable, look into this [How to get the Desktop path in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080634/how-to-get-the-desktop-path-in-java)